# How to define roles with ngxPermissions

Tags: javascript, angular, permissions

When I add roles in my angular project on my application component with :

```
this._ngxRolesService.addRole('ADMIN', () => {
     return true;
});
```

and then in my page's view :

```
<div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN']" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end start" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxFlex="30">
      <button mat-raised-button class="mat-accent" (click)="newAdd()">
                        Add
      </button>
</div>
```

the button doesn't appear. Even more, when I choose

```
 <div *ngxPermissionsExept="['ADMIN']" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end start" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxFlex="30">
      <button mat-raised-button class="mat-accent" (click)="newAdd()">
                        Add
      </button>
</div>
```

the button appear.... I'm authenticated with an ADMIN account and my role is : ADMIN.

Can someone help me please ? I think I don't understand how to define a role in Angular with ngx-permissions.

Comment: Can replicate the code on stackblitz? @adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Troubleshooting

Just perform following checks -

1.You have imported the `NgxPermissionsModule` in `AppModule`

```
NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot()
```

2.Do not forget to load permission.

```
this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(['ADMIN'])
```

> Note : you can get these roles from Asynchronous call as well.

You can refer this sample working demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/n6Wa6hXg0JzI6e050wBt?p=preview